# C# check if variable only contains given string

Tags: c#, string, contains

I am trying to use a variable called game.PlayMode which contains a semicolon-separated list of Play Modes input by the user. The variable can literally contain anything.

An example value:

```
Single Player; 2-Player; 3-Player; Co-Op; Versus; Alternate
```

I want to check if game.PlayMode ONLY contains Single Player but I am not sure how to do that.

So far:

```
if (game.Playmode.Contains("Single Player"))
        {
           Players = "1";
        }
```

But I know this will also return true with the example value above. How can I make sure my code returns true only if the string is an exact match?

Comment: & contains no semicolons?

Comment: You probably should convert the string to all lower or upper case as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variable `Playmode` only contains "Single Player" it is equal to that string, right?

```
if (game.Playmode.Trim().Replace(";", "")  == "Single Player")
{
    Players = "1";
}
```

.. and just in case if there is a semicolon, let's remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can simply use the == operator:

```
if (game.Playmode == "Single Player")
{
   Players = "1";
}
```

It might be a better idea to remove any `;` and any white spaces and only then do the comparison:

```
if (Playmode.Replace(";","").Trim()=="Single Player")
{
    Players = "1";
}
```